# Drop interaction delegate for uiwebview : ios11

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

```
//drop delegate
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle 
session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self)
}
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { imageItems in
        let images = imageItems as! [NSString]
        //self.imageView.text = images.first as String?
        //let string="<html><body> \(images.first!)  </body></html>"
        self.imageView.loadHTMLString(images.first! as String, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

here I tried text string from safari and trying to put in uiwebview...but it's not working.

Comment: Check this,may be it help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61995788/2332059