# Enable SplitView and MultiTask iPad hybrid app. Drop interaction

Tags: ipad, drag-and-drop, multitasking, splitview

We have on ionic iPad app, using cordova / capacitor platform. We enabled the split view for iPad 13 using following link https://en.gg/enable-ipad-split-screen-feature-in-an-ionic-or-cordova-app/
its working fine.

We are checking to give support for drag and drop feature like 
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios13-ipad-pro-multitasking-drag-drop-animation.gif

We just want to receiver end alone, here our question how we achieve this in cordova / capacitor application

When checking the native document, we need to enable view as drop destination for application, how we did this for ionic app
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drop_destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for my case

For enable splitView and multitask to custom view(UKWebView) drag and drop interaction

Full Source and Document available 
http://blogs.specialapps.in/SplitView_MultiTasking